# Graphical random generator

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there a random generator for linux with a nice GUI, which can generate a random integer between two integers and display it with a large fontsize?

Comment: What you gonna do? Mental Maths?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I don't know any software. Google didn't come up with something either. Guess this is too simple a problem. It should be about 30 lines of code if you wrote it in a scripting language. You could also create a LibreOffice spreadsheet to do that. Shouldn't be terribly difficult.

#### Edit 1:

[image: pseudo-random number generator - perl gui script]

Below is a quick and dirty perl script I coded. You should be able to modify it yourself. When you run it with `perl nameOfTheScript.pl` or make it executable with `chmod u+x nameOfTheScript.pl` and then double click it, it will look like in the picture above.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# © 2011 con-f-use@gmx.net. Use permitted under MIT license: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
use Gtk2 '-init'; # relies on the gnome toolkit bindings for perl

$size = 1e5;   # fontsize in 0.001 pt (only god knows why)

sub randomizeLabel {   #### this does the actual randomisation
    $min = int($entry1->get_text);
    $max = int($entry2->get_text);
    $rand = int(rand($max-$min+1)) + $min;
    $diplabel->set_markup( "<span size=\"$size\">$rand</span>" );
}
#### the rest is gui stuff:
$window = Gtk2::Window->new('toplevel');
$window->set_title('Random Integer Generator');
$window->signal_connect(destroy => sub { Gtk2->main_quit; });
$window->signal_connect(delete_event => sub { Gtk2->main_quit; });
$window->set_border_width(10);
$vbox = Gtk2::VBox->new(0, 5);   $window->add($vbox); $vbox->show;

$diplabel = Gtk2::Label->new;
$diplabel->set_markup("<span size=\"$size\">0</span>");
$vbox->add($diplabel);          $diplabel->show;

$entry1 = Gtk2::Entry->new;     $vbox->add($entry1);    $entry1->show;
$entry2 = Gtk2::Entry->new;     $vbox->add($entry2);    $entry2->show;

$button = Gtk2::Button->new("Generate!");
$button->signal_connect(clicked => \&randomizeLabel, $window);
$vbox->add($button);            $button->show;

$window->show;    Gtk2->main;
exit 0;
```

#### Edit2

[ObsessiveFOSS](https://askubuntu.com/users/54298/obsessivefoss) asked me to include another generator for random numbers (as it is this script uses Perl's build-in one). You can see a sketch on howto do it in [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/178487/17789).

Comment: +1 - the fact you cared enough to write a script to do that is amazing.

Comment: It is nice to see that you spent time on providing a script for this. Great!

Comment: Glad you like it.

Comment: @con-f-use it would be nice if you could release it in the gpl license .

Comment: @Alaukik Would MIT License be fine with you too. It's more permissive and GPL compatible?

Comment: @con-f-use absolutely ! i just suggested gpl since some people don't want their code to be used in proprietary software .

Comment: This led to a question on how to use GPL and MIT licenses correctly: http://askubuntu.com/q/46380/17789

Comment: Can you make an option for a CSPRNG like [Blum Blum Shub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub)?

Comment: It's a Perl script that is fairly easy to edit. Anyone could implement a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator. All one had to do is change the `randomizeLabel` subroutine. I'm pretty sure you'd manage to do that in less than two hours even if you have no previous knowledge of Perl. With the BBS the harder question is how to choose p,q, and the seed to have it reasonably secure.

Comment: @ObsessiveFoss: I added another answer for you. It's incomplete but you'll get the drift and be able to complete it.

Comment: @con-f-use: I've proposed a pure QML version of this generator.

Answer (score 4):

[ObsessiveFOSS](https://askubuntu.com/users/54298/obsessivefoss) asked to implement the [Blum, et al.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub) cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator. Here is my sketch on how to do it. The other code stays the same as in my [earlier answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/45867/17789). One just has to **replace the `randomizeLabel` subroutine and insert this code** instead:

```
use bigint;

# Kinda large primes
$p = 338047573;   # Any pair of large primes will suffice here...
$q = 4182249941;  #+...as long as they fullfill the congruence check below
$rand = 7;    # Seed for the random number generator (x_0 in the wiki)

sub errMsg {
    $dialog = Gtk2::MessageDialog->new($window, 'destroy-with-parent', 'error', 'ok', $_[0]);
    $dialog->signal_connect (response => sub { exit 1; });
    $dialog->run;
}

# Check congruence 3 mod 4 (for quadratic residue)
if( ($p-3)%4 == 0 ) { errMsg('Error: Variable p is ill choosen.'); }
if( ($q-3)%4 == 0 ) { errMsg('Error: Variable q is ill choosen.'); }
# Note: For large cycle lengths gcd(φ(p-1), φ(q-1)) should also be small,...
#+...where φ is Euler's totient function but this is not checked here

# Compute Modulus in Blum Blum Shub
$M = $p*$q;

sub randomizeLabel { # This does the actual randomization
    $min = int($entry1->get_text); $max = int($entry2->get_text); # Boundaries for the desired random range from the input filed of the GUI (included for convenience when modifying the script - not used here)

    # Blum Blum Shub pseudo random number generator
    $rand = ($rand*$rand) % $M;

    # Here you have to extract the bits and shift them in range
    $randout = $rand & (2**6-1); # Change this line. It's an example and extracts the five least significant bits! To extract the ten LSBs use '(2**11-1)' and so on...
    # $randout = ...$min...$max...; # shift it in the right range (not done here)

    $diplabel->set_markup( "<span size=\"$size\">$randout</span>" );
}
```

As mentioned it is incomplete. One would have to use bitwise operators to extract useful random numbers, shift and scale them to fit between `$min` and `$max`. Right now the input for minimum and maximum is unused.

Comment: I suspect there is a Perl module for CSPRNG that does a better job than my script.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done very easily with QML today:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

Rectangle {
    id: mainView
    width: units.gu(30) 
    height: units.gu(40)
    Column {
        id: generator
        spacing: units.gu(1)
        anchors.horizontalCenter: mainView.horizontalCenter
        Text {
            id: ramdom_number
            text: "0"
            font.pointSize: 100
            anchors.horizontalCenter: generator.horizontalCenter
        }
        TextField {
            id:min
            text: "0"
        }
        TextField {
            id: max
            text: "100"
        }
        Button {
            text: "Generate!"
            width: generator.width
            onClicked: ramdom_number.text = Math.floor((Math.random()*(max.text-min.text+1))+min.text);
        }
    }
}
```

Run this code with `qmlscene`:

[image]